# Batch file run using PHP works but only displays last line

Tags: php, batch-file, registry

I have a batch file that displays a list of registry keys.

10000
20000
30000
40000
..etc.

Using PHP, I can display the output of the batch file:

```
echo exec('file.bat');
```

This only shows me 40000 though, not the other three entries. How can I see everything?

Comment: Don't forget to tick the checkmark next to your chosen solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

`exec()` returns the last line from STDOUT.  You can pass a second parameter to capture all of the STDOUT.

```
exec($command, $output = array());
```

Then all of the output text will be in `$output`.